# Google Sheets API: error 401 on POST (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api, http-status-code-401

I'm not very experienced with javascript, but the google sheets API is driving me crazy. Took forever to get it to call a range, and now I can't get it to append or update the sheet.

I have done everything in the API setup, I have my API key, client ID, access tokens, all of that, but I can't figure out how to successfully POST to my sheet, and my code is now spaghetti from trying.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I have a button, where onclick it appends a range with the current date, but doing so returns a 401 error, meaning I don't have active credentials. However, I'm signed in, I've tried about 10 different ways of providing the token, and can't update the sheet. here's what I currently have for the onclick function:

CODE EDITED FROM ORIGINAL POST

```
function fv1Passivated() {
  let values = [
    [
      currentDate
    ],
  ];
  values = values;
  const body = {
    values: values,
  };
  try {
    gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
      spreadsheetId: SHEET_ID,
      range: 'FV1!A2:A',
      valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
      resource: body,

    }).then(function() {
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSignInStatus);
      updateSignInStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    }).then((response) => {
      var result = response.result;
      console.log(`${result.updates.updatedCells} cells appended.`);
      if (callback) callback(response);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return;
  }
};
```

And I have no idea how to even start untangling this into something that appends the current date to the end of the range. I'm going a little crazy, as I'm only halfway through freecodecamp's javascript module. Can anyone help? This question is on here a bunch, where people state the need for OAuth over api key, but with zero explanation on how to do that and it's breaking my newbie brain trying to figure it out.

Tried the google api's documentation for a simple write command. Expected it to work, but here we are. Error 401 returned in browser when launching it against localhost.

Comment: I never used this API but it seems like a bad idea to initialize it EVERY time the button is pressed. Why don't you start fresh again and go little by little? Maybe this quickstart doc can help you. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

Comment: The quickstart is a GET method, which is working just fine for me now. Here is he POST method documentation that this began as: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

As for initializing it every time I hit the button: attempted to fit in a fix I saw somewhere else, I've kind of lost track of things. I'll try cutting it out now.